# why Tabbar selected item is always 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I tried to print this value from another class but it is always showing selected `tabbar` index as 0

Why? is there any other method to identify which tab is selected now?

in my 2nd class `tableviewcontroller` `didselect` `method I am trying to print the following line

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    sharedManager=[Mymanager sharedManager]; 
    sharedManager.navigationBarTitle=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
    NSLog(@"%d",self.tabBarController.selectedIndex);

}
```

but it is always showing **0** ?

I need different index for different tab?

**my intention is to identify tabs and call method now i change that to call four different methodes 
but when i created one object and tried to call method it not displaying why?**

**My APpdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"internet connection" object:self];
    dispatch_queue_t connectivityThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.ttt.test.connectivity", NULL);

    dispatch_async(connectivityThread, ^{
        while (true){
            if([GMMConnectivity hasConnectivity])
                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InternetCheck" object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
            else
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InternetCheck" object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

            usleep(5000000);
        }
    });

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
  // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
  // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


}
//-(void)recentPages:(NSString *)pageNumber
//{
//    //NSLog(@"%@",pageNumber);
//}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that self.tabBarController isn't nil?

Comment: its 0 ..the value is 0

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaking `UITableView` for `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"selected tab index => %d", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
```

Comment: iam getting an error like @property tabbarcontroller not found on object type of my appdelegate class

Comment: @Diy   u there?      hello?

Comment: you have placed tabbar in storybopard ?? Make a global instance and connect to outlet let me know if you have issues i'll post reference code.

Comment: I'm not so happy..got another problem webview is not showing complete html page

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
NSUInteger index = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items indexOfObject:self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem];    
NSLog(@"Index: %d", index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take object of tabbar & get selected index of it. Suppose that you have tabbar in application delegate. So, from below code you can get selected index of tabbar.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%d", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

For TabbarController index change , you need to implement its delegate protocol. This delegate protocol should be implement as a rootviewcontroller or add inside any viewcontroller where you are adding your tabbarcontroller

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark - Tab bar Delegate

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    int i=tabBarController.selectedIndex;

    NSLog(@"selected tab index => %d", i);

    switch (i) {

        case 0:
            [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
            break;

        case 1:
            [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
            break;

        case 2:
            [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
            break;

        case 3:
            [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

At every index of tab bar you have to implement different - different view controller and inside viewWillAppear of every child view controller you can log its index value.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"selected tab value=> %d", appDel.tabBarController.selectedIndex);


}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: in my tabbarcontains four viewcontrooler where i should add

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable such that it is accessbile in your classes were you want to get the selected item and set the same variable in tabbar delegate.

```
@interface iPadAppDelegate : NSObject < UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

---

```
(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Hope this helps

Comment: please tell me wer i place this?

Comment: declare a variable in appdelegate or any other class that is accessible to your required method.

Comment: in which class u have the created the tabbarcontroller u can try with any one of the above delegate method but u have to conform in your header class about the delegate. So that the delegate gets called.
Note:- see my edited code

Comment: i just embed one tabbar controller to viewcontroller in storyboard. that class is almost empty

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html